# SQL to Extract all 30 minute or 60 minute time periods in a day that aren't reserved

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a reservation table that contains variable time ranges in a given day. They are reserved time slots of 30 minutes, 60 minutes, any given minute range that a user entered.

What I would like to do is create a SQL statement that can give me all time periods in a given day that aren't reserved. The user could specify the minute range (30 minute, 60 minute, 90 minute) intervals. Where do I even begin?

Reserved table is basic:

```
ROOM, RESERVED_DATE, FROM_TIME, TO_TIME
A     09/02/2014     9:00 AM    10:00 AM
B     09/02/2014     11:00 AM   12:00 PM
C     09/02/2014     1:30 PM    2:00 PM
```

I would allow the user to say they want all available rooms between business hours (8:00 AM - 4:30 PM) that are within a specific increment (30 mins, 60 mins, 90 mins).

Comment: You need to start with a table that has all the available time slots. Then you do a left join with your reservations.

Comment: Do the reservations always fall on the 30 minute mark or can you have a reservation from 9:13 - 9:43?

Comment: I would say, generally, they fall on hour and half hour times. They could potentially fall on quarters, although this is rare.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I'd take. This takes your @minimum_interval and finds an interval that is greater than that. As written, it does not include before and after. You can address that either by inserting a dummy date into the table as the start date/time and end date/time, or build that as a union in the cte (preferred).

essentially all it's doing is ordering by start time the doing a datediff on the [to] column and the [next] column, with [next] being calculated with the lag function. This keeps you from having to have a dedicated table, which is also why I'd build in a dummy start and end meeting in the cte; as the data is not stored, it doesn't have to be updated. You could store start and end times in a meta data construct to allow different "open" periods for different rooms.

Also, you can add the PARTITION clause to the lag function to allow this to work without specifying the room.

This was an interesting exercise, thanks for asking the question!

```
declare @date [datetime] = cast(current_timestamp as [date]);
declare @minimum_interval [int] = 15
    , @room           [sysname] = N'A';
declare @reservation table (
[room]   [sysname]
, [from] [datetime]
, [to]   [datetime]);
insert into @reservation
        ([room],[from],[to])
values      (N'A',N'20140902 09:00',N'20140902 10:00'),
        (N'A',N'20140902 10:00',N'20140902 11:00'),
        (N'A',N'20140902 13:00',N'20140902 14:00');
with [builder]
 as (select [room]
            , [from]
            , [to]
            , lag ([from]
                   , 1
                   , 0)
                over (
                  order by [from] desc) as [next]
     from   @reservation
     where  [room] = @room)
select [room]
   , [from]
   , [to]
   , [next]
from   [builder]
where  datediff(minute
            , [to]
            , [next]) > @minimum_interval;
```

Comment: That is correct. The original question did not state a version, so there is no reason for me not to use what is the current version, which is SQL Server 2012.